# Cannot read property 'length' of null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/averages-of-numbers/train/javascript) challenge on codewars, it passed all the test but I got an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

so I can't past the challenge. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code ?

```
function averages(numbers) {
  for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers.length < 2 || numbers[i] === ""){
      return [];
    } else {
      numbers[i] = (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1]) / 2;
    }
  }
  numbers.pop();
  return numbers
}
```

Comment: well, what do you expect `length` to be if `null` is passed as parameter?

Comment: you're passing `numbers` to your function, wich should be an array, if not, it will show that error. So be carefull about always passing an array, even if it's only 1 number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an important part of the instructions that you aren't handling:

> If the array has 0 or 1 values or is null or None, your method should return an empty array.

```
function averages(numbers) {
  if (!numbers) return []; // return empty array

  for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers.length < 2 || numbers[i] === ""){
      return [];
    } else {
      numbers[i] = (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1]) / 2;
    }
  }
  numbers.pop();
  return numbers
}
```

Comment: There is an inbuilt method `Array.isArray` that should be used; This method will still throw an error if I call it with `{a: 2}`. Also, not adding a -1 to the loop iterator will result in a NaN (not a number) result in the last number (through it will be pop'd out, this is not mandatory, but bad behavior); Look down to my answer, I explained it there

Answer (score 1):

You just need to test if the parameter is null

```
  //test if numbers is null
  if(numbers == null){
    return [];
  }
  for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers.length < 2 || numbers[i] === ""){
      return [];
    } else {
      numbers[i] = (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1]) / 2;
    }
  }
  numbers.pop();
  return numbers
```

Comment: Better: `if (Array.isArray(numbers) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
function averages(numbers) {
  if(numbers)
  {
    for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
      if(numbers.length < 2 || numbers[i] === ""){
        return [];
      } else {
        numbers[i] = (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1]) / 2;
      }
    }
    numbers.pop();
    return numbers
  }
  else
  {
    return [];
  }

}
```

Just add a null check to ur numbers variable. Then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To correct your code:

```
function averages(numbers) {
  if (!Array.isArray(numbers)) {
    return [];
  }
  for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers.length < 2){
      return [];
    } else {
      numbers[i] = (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1]) / 2;
    }
  }
  numbers.pop();
  return numbers
}
```

I use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check that it is really an array. It is an inbuilt function, so you should use it.

You can check this and the length in one step, saving more steps (look the example below).

To provide a cleaner solution:

```
function averages(numbers) {
  if (!Array.isArray(numbers) || numbers.length < 2) {
    return [];
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++){
      numbers[i] = (numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]) / 2;
  }
  numbers.pop();
  return numbers
}
```

It works fine, I also added a "-1" to the loop, as the last number will become "NaN" (Not a Number), because there is no element after it and `(10 + undefined) / 2 => NaN / 2 => NaN`. This also adds an unnecessary step to your algorithm.

## To make it complete

Another solution might be Array:map:

```
function averages(numbers) {
  if (!Array.isArray(numbers) || numbers.length < 2) {
    return [];
  }
  numbers.map(function(val, idx, arr) {
    arr[idx] = (val + arr[idx+1]) / 2;
  });
  numbers.pop();
  return numbers;
}
```